# How do I convert the results shown below into a ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview

how data is presented on screen
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U59WO.jpg)
[image]

I want these data to be presented as list view on the screen. I have some code relating to list view in Java, and there is also code for list view and textview on the xml file. I have tried presenting the results as list view but it did not work out.

Thank you in advance! :)

(Edited - I have wrote the code for customlayout.xml and activitymain.xml in Android Studio exactly as you gave)

```
 public class Viewstudent extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseManager myDb;
EditText sid, fn, ln, ge, cs, ag, ad;

ArrayList<String> student_id = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> student_name = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> student_lastname = new ArrayList<>();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);

    myDb = new DatabaseManager(this);



    sid = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sid);
    fn = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fn);
    ln = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ln);
    ge = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ge);
    cs = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cs);
    ag = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ag);
    ad = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ad);

    ListView listView  = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);


    Cursor res = myDb.getAllDataStudent();
    while(res.moveToNext()){
        student_id.add(res.getString(0));
        student_name.add(res.getString(1));
        student_lastname.add(res.getString(2));
    }

}

class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return student_id.size();//return count of array
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Set the general style
        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customlayout,null);
        TextView id = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sid);
        TextView name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.fn);
        TextView lastname = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ln);

        id.setText(student_id.get(position));
        name.setText(student_name.get(position));
        lastname.setText(student_lastname.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }
}


 }
```

Comment: You need to make a `custom adapter` and `viewholder`.Set this view to `builder.setView(viewID)` . You can use one `textview` or multiple as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

First put ListView in activity_main.xml file.

```
    <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView"></ListView>
```

Then in MainActivity.java file.

```
     ListView listView  = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Declare all the variables as array list.

```
    ArrayList<String> student_id = new Arraylist<>();
    ArrayList<String> student_name = new Arraylist<>();
    ArrayList<String> student_rollno = new Arraylist<>();
```

Then on onCreate() method

```
    Cursor res = myDb.getAllDataStudent();
     while(res.moveToNext()){
    student_id.add(res.getString(0));
    student_name.add(res.getString(1));
    student_rollno.add(res.getString(2));
    }
```

Create a new layout file customlayout.xml in layout folder.
Create the requited TextViews in this file like.Remeber the style and placement will become general to your ListView

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/sid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rollno"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"/>
```

Create a CustomAdapter class in MainActivity.java

```
    class CustomAdaper extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return student_id.size();//return count of array
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Set the general style
        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.customlayout,null);
        TextView id = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sid);
        TextView name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView rollno = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rollno);

        id.setText(student_id.get(position));
        name.setText(student_name.get(position));
        rollno.setText(student_rollno.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Now in onCreate method below

```
    ListView listView  = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Add the following code.

```
    CustomAdaper customAdaper = new CustomAdaper();
    lisview.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

You can now run your code.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much! I don't have any errors showing in Android Studio but when I click on the "View Record" screen on my app, there is nothing shown. It appears as a blank screen. I have edited this post to show the changes made....

Comment: have you got the result/

Comment: Yeah..I just edited the post now and posted a picture of the result. Its just a blank screen when I click to view the record.

Comment: wait a minute i will just tell you.

Comment: I edited this question above and posted the code there. Is there any other way you can view my code?

Comment: just a minute let me see.

Comment: you have not populated the ArrayList<String> with data. So just after you have initialized tour database use the code Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllStudentDate(); and following code that i mentioned above to populate ArrayList<String>.Currently your ArrayList is Empty so there is nothing shown in your screen.Got it?

Comment: Thank you very very much! it worked :) But now something is wrong with the display...all the information are shown crammed up together. I'm trying to work on them right now.

Comment: ranjitvamadevan47420@gmail.com